# Swift: How to manually call CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, function, location, cllocation

So normally when you try to grab a user's location using CLLocation, you'll use the `didUpdateLocations` method which(if everything has gone well) will be called when using `locationManager.startUpdatingLocations()`.

But I need to be able to manually call the function that gets the location so I can use a completion handler with it. How would I be able to get the user's location after start updating locations without using the `didUpdateLocations` method?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. What completion handler are you talking about? You are supposed to use the `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` to know when the location manager has finished updating the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the `CLLocationManager`'s `location` property at any time.  This will have the most recently determined location.  It may be nil if no location has been determined.

If you are targeting iOS 9 & later then you can use the `requestLocation` method to request a single location update.  The location update will be delivered to `didUpdateLocations` as usual.  There is no synchronous/blocking "request location, wait for it to update and return the location to me" method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "manually call CLLocation". After you start updating locations, the system begins calling your `didUpdateLocations` method. The first locations you get may have pretty poor accuracy. To get a good location you really need to check the accuracy and wait until you get a location that meets your requirements before you accept it.

I haven't used the new `requestLocation` method yet, so I don't know how it acts with regard to the poor results you get when you first request locations. The docs say "The location fix is obtained at the accuracy level indicated by the desiredAccuracy property" but supposedly `startUpdatingLocations` also honors the desired accuracy and the first few readings you get from it tend to be quite bad if the GPS was off when you called `startUpdatingLocations`.

In any case, both approaches call `didUpdateLocations` with the result/results.

If you want to invoke a closure/completion handler once you obtain a location then I suggest you create your own location manager singleton. Let's call it `MyLocationManager`.

You could give it a method `getLocation(completion:)` and have it take a completion block. The implementation would either start location updates or call `requestLocation` (if that method gives back locations that are dependably good the first time). It would also save away the completion handler closure in an (optional) instance variable. In MyLocationManager's implementation of didUpdateLocations it would check for a completion handler and call it if one was found, and then nil out the completion handler.